# Could being caught working illegally in Taiwan affect my entry to Singapore?

Tags: singapore, vietnamese-citizens

I'm a Vietnamese student in Taiwan. Last year I was punished because of working illegally, but I can stay here until I graduate. However, I now have a bad record about working illegally.

Next year, I intend to travel with some friends to Singapore for 6 days but I am scared that with my bad record, they will refuse my entry.

Is that likely?

Comment: May I ask just as a side comment, what kind of punishment did they impose on your case? Only some fine was charged? If there's nothing marked on your passport than most likely that you'll be fine.

Comment: I was charged and if I depart from Taiwan, I cannot come back within 3 years. So now I dont know whether they mark anything on my passport or not.

Comment: Is there anything *written* on your physical passport?

Comment: No. They didnt write anything on my passport. So if they mark anything on my passport, its hard to me to entry Singapore? and If not, everything is ok, right?

Answer (score 8):

**You should be fine.** Since you were not deported from Taiwan, and you are still legally resident there, there is no record of you working illegally in your passport and this will not be visible to Singaporean immigration.

As long as you have a return ticket to Taiwan, a good reason to go back (your studies) and enough money to cover a week's stay, Singapore will let you in.

Comment: I havent deport from Taiwan because I have to wait until my graduation that is this August. After that I'll come back Vietnam. and Since I come back, I cannot come to Taiwan within 3 years. So I dont know whether they mark anything in my passport or not. Next year, I'll deport from Vietnam to go to Singaport. Of course I'll have return ticket between Singapore and Vietnam and have enough money to cover my trip. So do you think I can entry?